# How to use google maps to pinpoint a location as a html form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, forms, http-post

Is it possible to integrate google maps api into a html form where a user can select a specific pin point location in the form of co-ordinates and submit them with your form?

I am using asp.net with Razor views, however I doubt that will effect the answer to this question in anyway.

I have had a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and cant seem to find using the maps api as a form input. Unless maybe im' blind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a [draggable marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#draggable) and store the lat/lng values in hidden inputs on `dragend` ([event docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)).

```
// Place a draggable marker on the map
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable:true,
    title:"Drag me!"
});

//get marker position and store in hidden input
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById("latInput").value = evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById("lngInput").value = evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an eventlistener initializing the marker first.

```
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      //position: new google.maps.LatLng(yourLat, yourLng),

  });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
        $("#yourinputlat").val(this.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6));
        $("#yourinputlng").val(this.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6));
    });
```

I've been using this to get the location with latitude and longitude from a google map and then insert it in an input to be sent with the POST

Comment: Sorry both answers where very similar. Derek S was first however. But I do appreciate your response and have voted you up.

Comment: No problem, hope both answers help you with your issue